# react check spesific user if exiest with state check

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

i am new to react and i have a little problem
i create a small project i did everything but i have a small issue
i have a varible and he has find method and he check if the userName && password field from the input are the same
but i get both of the userName and password with state to evrey field
and when i dont get the spesific user (not have match between the current field to the find)
i dont have to solution to get the user as undifend and return it..
i add this to sandbox :
https://codesandbox.io/s/priceless-fast-xrpxlu?file=/src/components/Homepage.jsx
plus add here the  app.js

i just need the get the spesific user from the users state
and if is the same it will get me to another page (this work)
but if the details not correct it will return (dosent work)

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Signup from "./components/Signup";
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import Homepage from "./components/Homepage";
import AdminPage from "./components/AdminPage";
import SpecificUser from "./components/SpecificUser";
import "./components/style.css";
function App() {
  const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
  const [specificUserName, setSpecificUserName] = useState();
  const [specificPassword, setSpecisifcPassword] = useState();

  const specificUser = users.find((user) => {
    return (
      user.userName === specificUserName && user.password === specificPassword
    );
  });

  const existUserCheck = (checkUserInp) => {
    const checkUserFilter = users.filter((user) => {
      if (user.userName === checkUserInp) return user;
    });
    return checkUserFilter.length !== 0 ? true : false;
  };
  const updateUser = (userInp) => {
    if (typeof specificUser == "undefined") return;

    const afterMap = users.map((user) => {
      if (user.userName === specificUser.userName) {
        return userInp;
      } else return { ...user };
    });

    setUsers(afterMap);
    return true;
  };
  const addUser = (id, userName, password, confirmPassword, money) => {
    const createdUser = {
      id: Number(id),
      userName: userName,
      password: password,
      confirmPassword: confirmPassword,
      money: Number(money),
      expense: []
    };
    if (updateUser()) {
      updateUser(createdUser);
      return;
    }
    setUsers([...users, createdUser]);
  };
  const transferMoney = (companyInp, priceInp) => {
    const expense = specificUser.expense;
    const companyName = companyInp;
    const price = priceInp;
    expense.push({ companyName: companyName, price: Number(price) });
    const afterMap = users.map((user) => {
      if (user.userName === specificUser.userName) return { ...user, expense };
      else return { ...user };
    });
    setUsers(afterMap);
  };
  const deleteUser = () => {
    const afterDeleteUser = users.filter((user) => {
      return user.userName !== specificUserName;
    });
    setUsers(afterDeleteUser);
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
          <Route
            path="/"
            element={
              <Homepage
                setSpecisifcPassword={setSpecisifcPassword}
                setSpecificUserName={setSpecificUserName}
                specificUser={specificUser}
              />
            }
          ></Route>
          <Route
            path="/register"
            element={
              <Signup addUserFunc={addUser} existUserCheck={existUserCheck} />
            }
          ></Route>
          <Route
            path="/:id"
            element={
              <SpecificUser
                specificUser={specificUser}
                transferMoney={transferMoney}
              />
            }
          />
          <Route
            path="/admin"
            element={
              <AdminPage
                deleteUser={deleteUser}
                users={users}
                specificUser={specificUser}
                setSpecificUserName={setSpecificUserName}
              />
            }
          ></Route>
          <Route
            path="/edit"
            element={<Signup addUserFunc={addUser} />}
          ></Route>
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          console.log(users);
        }}
      >
        Check Users
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: never ever ever store user credentials or lists client side. holy hacking target, batman.

Comment: You mean when i was using the find method on the use state?                          So how i can get the specific user when i using the find method? I need to get the deatils from the input field but i create the find method on app.js

Comment: you clearly have user passwords in plain text since you're searching on it. like, just don't do that  =)  credential stuff should always be a server side thing.

Comment: I dont understand you correctly             can you show me how to use it correctly?                                                    The find method is on app.js the the txt is on diffrent componente so how i will do it?